# Consuming OpenRasta services

Tags: c#, wcf, openrasta

Following advice on here, I am looking at whether to replace WCF with OpenRasta.

In Visual Studio, how do I consume an OpenRasta in the same way as I would a WCF/ASMX service e.g. Add a service reference, this handles the types using WSDL.

I can't find any examples which don't require a custom WebRequest and parse the xml, which for us is a significant step backwards for utilising a service in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenRasta is designed to give you RESTful services. To consume that, you might want to look at something like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) which is designed to act as a client/consumer for RESTful services.

Answer (score 3):

As Colin says, ReSTful services are by definition hypermedia oriented, so generating lots and lots of RPC style code a la WSDL is not doable, it would break hypermedia.

You can still happily generate datacontract-style classes from an xsd and read those from the xml, it's at most 4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks Seb. Do you have any examples of this on your wiki?

Comment: Seb - sorry for the sub question, but is OpenRasta Mono compliant?